mount an external azure storage account with aks cluster
i have created a storage class in my aks cluster and i have mounted it with my 2 pvc of sonarqube "data and extention" volumes , and every thing works. i have created the storage class in a diffrent resource groupe so when i destroy my cluster the storage class will remain and not deleted.
Now what i want is when creating the cluster again i want to mount the volumes "data and extentions" with the existing storage class but it keeps getting errors and i didnt found any good documentation of how to do it.
any ideas ?
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-data
  namespace: inf-core
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: sonar-azurefile
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
name: sonarqube-extensions
namespace: inf-core
spec:
accessModes:
- ReadWriteMany
storageClassName: sonar-azurefile
resources:
requests:
storage: 5Gi
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-deployment
  namespace: inf-core
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sonarqube
      tier: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sonarqube
        tier: web
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-sonarqube-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'chown -R 999:999 /opt/sonarqube']  
        volumeMounts:
        - name: sonarqube-data
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/data
        - name: sonarqube-extensions
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/lib/extensions
      - name: init-sysctl
        image: busybox
        command: ['sysctl', '-w', 'vm.max_map_count=262144']
        securityContext:
          privileged: true    
      containers:
      - name: sonarqube
        image: sonarqube:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        env:
        - name: SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sonarqube-secret
              key: SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME
        - name: SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sonarqube-secret
              key: SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD
        - name: SONAR_JDBC_URL
          value: jdbc:postgresql://postgres-service:5432/sonarqube
        volumeMounts:
        - name: sonarqube-data
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/data
        - name: sonarqube-extensions
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/lib/extensions
      volumes:
      - name: sonarqube-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sonarqube-data
      - name: sonarqube-extensions
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sonarqube-extensions


apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: sonar-azurefile
provisioner: file.csi.azure.com
allowVolumeExpansion: true
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
  - mfsymlinks
  - cache=strict
  - actimeo=30
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
  resourceGroup: AKS-STORAGECLASS


To ensure that your existing storage class and persistent volumes are correctly reattached to your new AKS cluster, make sure your Azure Storage Account and the associated file shares for sonarqube-data and sonarqube-extensions still exist in the specified resource group. Since your existing PVCs are bound to PVs that persist in a different resource group, you need to manually create PVs that reference the existing Azure File shares. This way, your new PVCs can bind to these manually created PVs.
Create a Kubernetes secret that contains the Azure Storage Account name and key
kubectl create secret generic azure-secret --from-literal=azurestorageaccountname=arkostor --from-literal=azurestorageaccountkey=$STORAGE_KEY


Create PVs for for sonarqube-data and sonarqube-extensions
data
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-sonarqube-data
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: sonar-azurefile
  azureFile:
    secretName: azure-secret
    shareName: sonarqube-data
    secretNamespace: default


extensions
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-sonarqube-extensions
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: sonar-azurefile
  azureFile:
    secretName: azure-secret
    shareName: sonarqube-extensions
    secretNamespace: default



Create PVC for the same data and extensions
data
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-data
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: sonar-azurefile
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi

extensions
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-extensions
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: sonar-azurefile
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi



Finally deploy your sonarqube
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sonarqube
      tier: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sonarqube
        tier: web
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-sonarqube-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'chown -R 999:999 /opt/sonarqube/data /opt/sonarqube/lib/extensions']
        volumeMounts:
        - name: sonarqube-data
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/data
        - name: sonarqube-extensions
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/lib/extensions
      - name: init-sysctl
        image: busybox
        command: ['sysctl', '-w', 'vm.max_map_count=262144']
        securityContext:
          privileged: true    
      containers:
      - name: sonarqube
        image: sonarqube:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        env:
        - name: SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sonarqube-secret
              key: SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME
        - name: SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sonarqube-secret
              key: SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD
        - name: SONAR_JDBC_URL
          value: jdbc:postgresql://postgres-service:5432/sonarqube
        volumeMounts:
        - name: sonarqube-data
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/data
        - name: sonarqube-extensions
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/lib/extensions
      volumes:
      - name: sonarqube-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sonarqube-data
      - name: sonarqube-extensions
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sonarqube-extensions


kubectl get pods -n default


This setup ensures that your storage remains persistent even if the AKS cluster is recreated.

@Lahmar Oussama is your issue resolved?
